# django.db.utils.operationalerror: <2006, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' <using password: YES>"

Tags: python, django

i used the command python manage.py migrate and the project settings.py are as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
'default':{
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'timesheetdb',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '123456',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': ''
}
```

I am getting an error of:
django.db.utils.Operationalerror:<2006,"access denied for user'root'@'localhost' ".

i get the same error with the command python manage.py runserver

Can you help?

Comment: Make sure the user is an admin/privileged user in your mysql instance.

Comment: Try adding the port, usually `3306` for mysql

Comment: i tried changing the PORT but it didnt work.I went on mysql and realised no password was set despite being set on project settings.py.I then added the password on mysql of the user account and it worked